# FileUload is static object or no?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I upload image with fileupload and save them to DB. this is my code:

```
 UploadHelper.SaveFile(fileUpload1, drop_doc.SelectedValue.ToString(), Session("TraceNo"), _UsersLog)
```

fileupload1 is in toolbox for asp.net. i want to know this file upload for some users that upload images concurrent is static object or no? concurrency occurred or no?

Comment: you can upload files concurrently but of course if it's thread-safe to _save_ them somewhere depends on your own code.

Comment: i send fileupload directly in my method. i want to know, its wrong? and i must create an object and put that with fileupload1?

Comment: It's OK, each HTTP request has its own instance of your page then instance methods/fields are thread-safe.

Comment: sometimes my images be replaced in db with images for other user. fileupload cache images and use other image?

Comment: FileUpload control doesn't cache but what happens inside UploadHelper.SaveFile() is _mistery_ ;)

Comment: This is SaveFile():
Dim fs As Stream = fileUP.PostedFile.InputStream 
 Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs) 
Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
 UploadHelper.InsertImgNameInDb( Trim(traceNo), Trim(prefix), Trim(imgName), bytes, _UsersLog) 
and this is t-sql in db:
 Insert RegNameOfImages ( TraceNo,Coding,ImgName,ImgContent) Values ( @traceNo,@Coding,@ImgName,@ImgContent)

Comment: Are you **sure** TraceNo isn't repeated? Is it a session variable, where/how it's first initialized?

Comment: yes TraceNo is not repeated. when user login, traceNo initialized.my problem is all of variable such traceno and other is true but just image content rewrite.....

Comment: You mean there is right record (traceNo, imgName and so on) in DB BUT imgContent is duplicated between some of them? What UploadHelper.InsertImgNameInDb does?

Comment: yes.in UploadHelper.InsertImgNameInDb just call sp that save image.